# How to sort an array of arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

In php I have a numerical array of associative arrays:

```
mainArray: 
[
  array1:['title':'Record a','order':'2'],
  array2:['title':'Record b','order':'4'],
  array3:['title':'Record c','order':'1'],
  array4:['title':'Record d','order':'3']
]
```

What is the simplest way to sort mainArray by the 'order' value of each associative array?

Thanks

Comment: [uasort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) is helpful for array() If multiple array then use [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `usort` function. Since PHP 5.4 you can use closure function:

```
usort($mainArray, function ($a, $b) {
  $a_val = (int) $a['order'];
  $b_val = (int) $b['order'];

  if($a_val > $b_val) return 1;
  if($a_val < $b_val) return -1;
  return 0;
});
```

Or version for PHP < 5.4:

```
usort($mainArray, 'myCompare');

function myCompare($a, $b) {
  $a_val = (int) $a['order'];
  $b_val = (int) $b['order'];

  if($a_val > $b_val) return 1;
  if($a_val < $b_val) return -1;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest version, using comparison function and `usort`:

```
usort($mainArray, function($a, $b) {
  return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
});
```

Comment: @Dharman, why not? Just checked on latest RC, works fine.

Comment: I can't remember why I said that. In hindsight my comment was not very helpful. Sorry

Answer (score -1):

I found this in the [php documentation comments for asort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)  See also the [sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) page, in the comments there are a few good candidates.

```
function named_records_sort($named_recs, $order_by, $rev=false, $flags=0)
{// Create 1-dimensional named array with just
 // sortfield (in stead of record) values
    $named_hash = array();
     foreach($named_recs as $key=>$fields)
             $named_hash["$key"] = $fields[$order_by];

 // Order 1-dimensional array,
 // maintaining key-value relations  
    if($reverse) arsort($named_hash,$flags=0) ;
    else asort($named_hash, $flags=0);

 // Create copy of named records array
 // in order of sortarray 
    $sorted_records = array();
    foreach($named_hash as $key=>$val)
           $sorted_records["$key"]= $named_recs[$key];

return $sorted_records;} // named_recs_sort()

function show_sorted_records($named_recs, $order_by, $rev=false, $flags=0)
{$sorted_records=named_records_sort($named_recs, $order_by, $rev, $flags);
foreach($sorted_records as $name=>$fields)
  {echo "<b>$name</b>   ";
   foreach($fields as $field=>$val)
          echo "$field = $val "; echo "<br>";}
} // show_sorted_records()

$girl_friends=array();
$girl_friends["Anna"]=
array("born"=>'1989-08-22',"cupsize"=>'B-',"IQ"=>105, "daddy"=>'rich');
$girl_friends["Zoe"]
=array("born"=>'1978-03-11',"cupsize"=>'C#',"IQ"=>130, "daddy"=>'poor');
$girl_friends["Lilly"]
=array("born"=>'1985-06-16',"cupsize"=>'DD',"IQ"=>90, "daddy"=>'nasty');

$order_by="cupsize"; echo "And the winners are: <br>";
show_sorted_records($girl_friends, $order_by, true);
```