# PHP Sort array by field?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [how to sort a multidemensional array by an inner key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545544/how-to-sort-a-multidemensional-array-by-an-inner-key)
> [How to sort an array of arrays in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978447/how-to-sort-an-array-of-arrays-in-php)

How can I sort an array like: `$array[$i]['title'];`

Array structure might be like:

```
array[0] (
  'id' => 321,
  'title' => 'Some Title',
  'slug' => 'some-title',
  'author' => 'Some Author',
  'author_slug' => 'some-author'
);

array[1] (
  'id' => 123,
  'title' => 'Another Title',
  'slug' => 'another-title',
  'author' => 'Another Author',
  'author_slug' => 'another-author'
);
```

So data is displayed in **ASC order** based off the **title field** in the array?

Comment: Michael: Tim was just being helpful. Searching first is a bit of a prerequisite here, and we get a _lot_ of questioners that don't appear to have searched/tried first.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Use [`usort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) which is built explicitly for this purpose.

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["title"], $b["title"]);
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

Comment: You can multiply by -1 to reverse the sort as well, just an FYI to anyone who may need to do so.

Comment: Starting PHP 5.3 you can use anonymous functions, which is helpful especially if you're inside a class in a namespace:
`usort($domain_array, function ($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
});
`

Comment: Just to add on a bit to @GabiLee, if you want the search field to be dynamic based on some variable you already have set, try this: usort($domain_array, function ($a, $b) use ($searchField) { return strcmp($a[$searchField], $b[$searchField]); }); This might be useful for example on a web page where the user can choose a field to sort by.

Comment: @KyleCrossman we can also pass the arguments in a different order to obtain a reverse sort.

Comment: For php7.4 and up `usort($array, fn($a, $b) => $a['title'] <=> $b['title']);`