# Best way to sort an array depending on a subvalue

Tags: php

I have an array created like that :

```
$myarray = array();
$myarray['id1'] = array('pos' => 3, 'data' => '...');
$myarray['id2'] = array('pos' => 1, 'data' => '...');
$myarray['id3'] = array('pos' => 2, 'data' => '...');
```

I would like to iterate on `$myarray` with the order of the `pos` value. How can I do that ?

The only way I see for the moment is recreate a new ordered array from the first one. That's ugly, of course...

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000005/php-sort-array-by-field). I want to keep the keys linked to my subarrays.

Comment: Have you even tried something ?

Comment: Yes, recreate a new array from the first one. That's ugly. Why downvoting ?

Comment: Duplicate... maybe. But reading the doc, the solution of the other question is not appropriate to this case.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17364127/3933332 <- And your solution is in there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `uasort` http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

to define custom sort functions:

```
uasort($myarray, "mySortFunction");

function mySortFunction($a, $b){
  return $a["pos"] - $b["pos"]; //or $b - $a, depending on desired order
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use uasort to save keys

```
$myarray['id1'] = array('pos' => 3, 'data' => '...');
$myarray['id2'] = array('pos' => 1, 'data' => '...');
$myarray['id3'] = array('pos' => 2, 'data' => '...');

uasort ($myarray, function($it1, $it2) { return $it1['pos'] - $it2['pos']; });
var_dump($myarray);

array(3) {
  ["id2"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["pos"]=>
    int(1)
    ["data"]=>
    string(3) "..."
  }
  ["id3"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["pos"]=>
    int(2)
    ["data"]=>
    string(3) "..."
  }
  ["id1"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["pos"]=>
    int(3)
    ["data"]=>
    string(3) "..."
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is very nice. I would like to accept it, but it doesn't work on one of my workstations with a too old version of php (5.2.17). The solution of dognose is more general.

Comment: @Caduchon No problem :) Moreover, it is the same